# Export data to SQL Server 2005 from CSV file

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005

Following **asp.net** code fetches data from CSV file and inserts it into SQL server 2005 table.

However, i need to specify Table name, Field names whose data will be fetched, plus mapping info(Mapping between 'column names of CSV' and 'column names of table') statically in code.

How can i modify below code so that it works for any Table name.
In short, Table name and Mapping should be handled **dynamically**.

```
public class CsvBulkCopyDataIntoSqlServer
{

    protected const string _truncateLiveTableCommandText = @"TRUNCATE TABLE Account";
    protected const int _batchSize = 100000;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        LoadCsvDataIntoSqlServer();

    }

    public static void LoadCsvDataIntoSqlServer()
    {
        // This should be the full path
        var fileName = @"D:\output.csv";
        var createdCount = 0;

        using (var textFieldParser = new TextFieldParser(fileName))
        {
            textFieldParser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
            textFieldParser.Delimiters = new[] { "," };
            textFieldParser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;

            // var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CMSConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            string connectionString = "Data Source= 172.25.10.4" + ";Initial Catalog= SFdata" + ";Persist Security Info=True;User ID= sa" + ";Password= Newuser@123";


            var dataTable = new DataTable("Account");


            // Add the columns in the temp table
            dataTable.Columns.Add("Name");
            dataTable.Columns.Add("shippingstreet");
            dataTable.Columns.Add("shippingpostalcode");
            dataTable.Columns.Add("ShippingCountry");
            dataTable.Columns.Add("shippingstate");

            //dataTable.Columns.Add("LastName");

            using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                sqlConnection.Open();

                // Truncate the live table
                using (var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(_truncateLiveTableCommandText, sqlConnection))
                {
                    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                // Create the bulk copy object
                var sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnection)
                {
                    DestinationTableName = "Account"
                };

                // Setup the column mappings, anything ommitted is skipped
                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Name", "Name");
                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("shippingstreet", "shippingstreet");
                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("shippingpostalcode", "shippingpostalcode");
                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("ShippingCountry", "ShippingCountry");
                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("shippingstate", "shippingstate");

                // Loop through the CSV and load each set of 100,000 records into a DataTable
                // Then send it to the LiveTable
                while (!textFieldParser.EndOfData)
                {
                    dataTable.Rows.Add(textFieldParser.ReadFields());

                    createdCount++;

                    if (createdCount % _batchSize == 0)
                    {
                        InsertDataTable(sqlBulkCopy, sqlConnection, dataTable);

                        break;
                    }
                }

                InsertDataTable(sqlBulkCopy, sqlConnection, dataTable);

                sqlConnection.Close();
            }
        }
    }

    protected static void InsertDataTable(SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy, SqlConnection sqlConnection, DataTable dataTable)
    {
        sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dataTable);

        dataTable.Rows.Clear();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use SQL Server Integration Services, it will make your life easier

Comment: SQL Server Integration Services has a set of UI Screens on which user has to make selection. Whereas, all my data transfer should be done in the background, so please help me by modifying the above code.